# Visualizar documentos em .PDF em pastas diferentes

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Bom dia!
Eu tenho um painel onde é postado vários arquivos PDF, porém são 3 pastas diferentes de acordo com cada tipo de arquivo. E nesse painel, eu preciso colocar um método onde a pessoa consiga visualizar o arquivo. Porém não sei como fazer essa busca em pastas diferentes.

Segue o trecho do código que lista os arquivos:

```
    </tr>
    <?
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `pdf`";
      $query = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
      //var_dump($resultado);exit;
      while($listar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    ?> 
        <tr>
          <td><?=$listar["nome"]?></td>
          <td><?if($listar["tipo"] == 1)echo"Licitações";
                if($listar["tipo"] == 2)echo"Edital";
                if($listar["tipo"] == 3)echo"Legislação";?></td>
          <td><a href="" class="btn btn-default" target="_blank">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Download</td>
          <td><a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm help" data-toggle="modal" title="Excluir PDF"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
        </tr>    
      <?}?>
```

Como pode ver,existe a pasta Uploads, e dentro dela legislacao, licitacoes e editais. Onde fica cada tipo de arquivo. Ao listar, eu coloquei para baixar o arquivo, mas não sei como buscar esse arquivo em pastas diferentes.

Comment: Voce quer baixar o arquivo do banco ou de um diretorio?

Comment: Quero baixar de um diretorio

Comment: https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/PHP_-_Download_de_arquivos

Comment: Isso deve lhe ajudar. Ao inves do span vc pode usar um link que aponte para o diretorio uploads/licitacao/nome_arquivo.pdf.